# Can tile, cement, and grout rubble be used as fill under crawl space vapor barrier?

Tags: bathroom, vapor-barrier, remodel

I am remodeling my bathroom (one of two) and was thinking how I can reuse the demolition debris instead of throwing it away. As one of my future projects was to encapsulate my crawl space, one of the steps was to put in a layer of gravel then the plastic vapor barrier. Not knowing the soundness of the idea, should I use the bathroom demo material in this fashion?

Comment: Many years ago when I was cutting into the brick wall holding my oven to make it a little wider and a lot taller to hold a double-oven, I found that there was quite a bit of construction debris filled inside the wall. That actually was good - if it was 100% solid brick/block it would have been even *more* work, and it was enough work (and dust...) already.

Answer (score 5):

All those things combined don't amount to much volume. If your goal is to install an inorganic layer for sanitation reasons, this doesn't do much for you. You'd need to be sure that no sharp edges protrude from the gravel layer and damage your vapor barrier or your knees.

If you really need to save refuse disposal costs, go ahead and bury it, but bury it deep.

Comment: How deep? I was think of leveling out the crawlspace - and this would be the aggregate to do so. As for sharp edges - I didn't consider this before, was this the reason why you suggested I bury it?

Comment: Yes, and for appearance. I don't particularly like _landfill chic_. I would want a uniform, smooth appearance in my home, even under poly sheeting.